# Render depth from framebuffer texture

Tags: opengl, textures, framebuffer, depth, depth-buffer

I've been trying to add SSAO (based on the tutorial here: http://john-chapman-graphics.blogspot.co.nz/2013/01/ssao-tutorial.html) to a project of mine and I've gotten stuck on rendering the depth correctly.

I have created a framebuffer texture to draw the depth to each frame. The texture itself looks correct when I draw it to a quad but I can't figure out how to correctly apply it to the whole scene.

Here's what the regular scene looks like:

[image]

And here's the applied depth texture:
[image]

Currently in my fragment shader I just use my regular texture coordinates (TexCoord0) to draw the depth texture. I'm guessing I need to change this but I don't have a clue what to change it to.
Here's the relevant fragment shader code:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 TexCoord0;

smooth in vec3 vNormal;
smooth in vec3 vWorldPos;
in mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

uniform sampler2D uDepthTex;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(uDepthTex, TexCoord0);
}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to fix this. I've read a lot of sample code online which seems to use regular texture coordinates to draw the depth.

EDIT:
Here's my framebuffer setup code:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &ssaoFramebufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFramebufferID);

glGenTextures(1, &ssaoDepthTextureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoDepthTextureID);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);

glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, ssaoDepthTextureID, 0);

glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

And the depth pass code I call each frame before regular draw:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFramebufferID);
glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

depthShader.Bind();
depthShader.SetUniformMatrixfv("depthMVP", camera.GetViewMatrix() * Matrix4::Perspective(60, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 10.0f));

DrawScene(true);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
```

My depth shaders, vertex:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 Position;

uniform mat4 depthMVP;

void main() {
    gl_Position = depthMVP * vec4(Position, 1.0);
}
```

fragment:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) out float fragmentdepth;

void main() {
    fragmentdepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}
```

EDIT2:
The glClear call where it currently is gives me a completely black texture. Putting it below the first glViewport call gives the depth image I displayed above though:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFramebufferID);
glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: You know the default output from a depth texture is already: `vec4 (r, r, r, 1.0)`, right? You can just write `FragColor = texture(uDepthTex, TexCoord0);`. As for the rest of the situation, the GLSL shader's not going to help explain this - the code where you setup your depth buffer, projection matrix, FBO, etc. is actually more relevant.

Comment: Yea I'm aware of that. My actual shader is a lot larger I just edited out the irrelevant stuff (point lights etc.) and that was an oversight. I've updated my question with some more information.

Comment: `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE` is also deprecated in GLSL 3.30. It has been deprecated since GLSL 1.30 (GL 3.0). That is when the behavior I mentioned in my first comment started to take effect and the reason `GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE` was removed. I am pretty sure that's not an actual problem here, but if you ran this code through something like gDEBugger, it would give you pretty much the same warning I did ;) As for your actual problem, you appear never to clear the FBO's depth buffer. You do clear color/depth in your code, but only ***prior*** to binding your FBO for the depth-only pass.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the GL_DEPTH_TEXTURE_MODE call. Moving glClear around seems to give me a black screen sometimes. I'll update my question to show what I mean.

Comment: Btw,you will probably need to linearize your depth values before writing them to the fragment output.Otherwise you won't see the correct visualization of it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is gl_FragCoord.xy, its the position of the current fragment as it will appear on your screen, instead of within the polygon. Simply sample the depth texture with gl_FragCoord.xy (first divide it by your screen resolution). This will put the correct depth value onto the visible polygon, however, this will not magically make your SSAO work.

Comment: gl_FragCoord seems like the right idea. I've noticed now though that no matter what I do to my depth fragment shader the texture always looks the same. Even when I intentionally add syntax errors I get the same image above.

Comment: are you catching compilation errors? if your shader doesnt compile, opengl will use the default pipeline, which may very well look exactly like what we see in the picture.

Comment: Well it turns out I had some other shaders binding during my draw pass. I removed those and I get a correct looking depth on a textured quad. Unfortunately I still can't apply the depth to the whole scene properly with gl_FragCoord [using this line currently vec4 depthColour = texture(uDepthTex, gl_FragCoord.xy);]. The scene looks white at first but flicks between different shades of grey when I move the camera.

Comment: Ok my bad. I missed the part about scaling gl_FragCoord.xy by the screen resolution. I have a working depth map now. I'll post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get it working thanks to some help in the comments:
[image]

My code is now as follows, fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 TexCoord0;

smooth in vec3 vNormal;
smooth in vec3 vWorldPos;
in mat4 ProjectionMatrix;

uniform sampler2D uDepthTex;
uniform float uWidth;
uniform float uHeight;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    vec2 res = gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(uWidth, uHeight);
    FragColor = texture(uDepthTex, res);
}
```

Framebuffer creation:

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &ssaoFramebufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFramebufferID);

glGenTextures(1, &ssaoDepthTextureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ssaoDepthTextureID);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, 1024, 768, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);
```

Depth draw code:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ssaoFramebufferID);
glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

depthShader.Bind();

glDisable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);

depthShader.SetUniformMatrixfv("depthMVP", Matrix4::Perspective(60, aspectRatio, 0.1f, 10.0f) * camera.GetViewMatrix());

DrawScene();

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
```

Comment: Ah the only depth buffer setup which worked for me finally. Thanks!